# How Can i order a model?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm a newbie in ember and I don't know how to sort a list of movies by title. 
I have a route index with a model hook:

```
export default Route.extend(RealtimeRouteMixin,{
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('movie');
  }
});
```

I render a component when this route is loaded. I set the model in the template

```
{{landing-page
  add=(action 'addMovie')
  movies=model
}}
```

Inside this component, there are other child's components. In one of them is a list of movie where I want to show the list of the movies sort by title.

```
//landing-page template
{{movie-list-header}}

{{movie-list
  movies=this.movies
}}

{{add-movie-form add=this.add
}}
```

```
//movive-list template
{{#each movies as |movie|}}
  {{movie-list/movie-list-item
    movie=movie
  }}
  <hr />
{{/each}}
```

I don't know what the best approach to do it. I've thought to sort the model in the route  but I don't know If I have to do it something like this

```
export default Route.extend(RealtimeRouteMixin,{
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('movie').then(funcion(data){
        // sort here ???
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489283/ember-sort-model-after-findall

Answer (score 0):

Your approach would work. Then [`sortBy`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.12/classes/EmberArray/methods/sortBy?anchor=sortBy) would do the trick.

The other approach is to put it somewhere in your component hierarch starting with the controller. A simple computed property will do the trick. [There is also a computed property macro](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.12/classes/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/methods/sort?anchor=sort).

Comment: I cant't use sortBy because I've recorded the item with

```javascript
this.store.createRecord('movie', {
        title,
        description,
        image,
        rating
      });
```


I've changed my code and now I use a computed property inside `landing-page`.

```javascript
  moviesSorted: computed.sort('movies',function(a,b){
    let aTitle = a.get('title');
    let bTitle = b.get('title');
    return aTitle < bTitle ? a : b;
  }),
```

But I don't get the list sorted

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to handle simple ordering in the template using [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers) as it sorts strings well with the least amount of boilerplate.  After installing that addon and restarting your ember server you can do this in your template with the [sort-by](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#sort-by) helper.

```
//movie-list template
{{#each (sort-by "title" movies) as |movie|}}
  {{movie-list/movie-list-item
    movie=movie
  }}
  <hr />
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller/component where your model you want to sort with property, you can mention following computed property:

sortedModel: sort('model', 'title:desc'),

you can import sort as follows:
import { sort } from '@ember/object/computed';

Now use sortedModel instead of model in templates/handlebars. I hope that make sense. Please let me know if you have any query?